# How to use multiple filters separately in one function

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

I'm using a filter (css class of the anchor) to select images for a featherlight lightbox. All images with one class are shown in one gallery. So I call each function separately. I use this code to show 2 different galleries on one page:

```
$('#content').each(function(_i, gallery) {
  $(gallery).featherlightGallery({
    variant: 'gal',
    filter: '.featured-image1'
  });
});
$('#content').each(function(_i, gallery) {
  $(gallery).featherlightGallery({
    variant: 'gal',
    filter: '.featured-image2'
  });
});
```

This 2 function are equal, only the filter changed. If there are more galleries I wonder if it is possible tho simplify this in one function. I've yet no idea, so ask this question here.

Comment: Why not just use a single (shared/common/whatever), `featured-image` class?

Comment: Seems like a straight up method with a variable passed in.

Comment: @James Hill: with one single class all images are open in one gallery. This is not what they should do. featured-image1 is a sepapate gallery. featured-image2 is a separate gallery... and so on. It works but can this be written simpler if there are > 10 gelleries?

Comment: @Taplar: what do you mean with variable pass in exactly?

Comment: You are familiar with functions in javascript, right?  `function aName (variable1, variable2, ...){ ..stuff.. }`  You can put your logic in one of those and pass in the filter value as an argument.  This is pretty basic javascript.

Comment: @Taplar: There are pretty basic holes in my knowledge, I think. I'll try it and will come back with my suggestion. Thank you for the istructions.

Comment: I tryed a lot but did not find the solution yet. Hmmm.